# Finding out $p$-torsion elements of an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, iwasawa-theory

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$. 
Then how to compute the $p$-torsion elements of $E$ over the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ using SAGE or any other means ? 
At least can we say whether $E(\mathbb{Q}_p)[p]=0$ or not ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose $p>2$ and that $E$ has good reduction. If the reduction $\tilde E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has no $p$-torsion then there is no $p$-torsion in $E(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. Otherwise look at the exact sequence
$$ 0\to E(\mathbb{Q}_p)[p]\to \tilde E(\mathbb{F}_p)[p]\to \hat E(p\mathbb{Z}_p)/p\hat E(p\mathbb{Z}_p).$$
Here $\hat E$ is the formal group. So to check if a $p$-torsion point $\tilde P$ in the reduction lifts to a $p$-torsion point in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ do the following. Take any lift $P\in E(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. Then $Q=pP\in \hat E(p\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is the image of $\tilde P$ under the boundary map. Now check if $Q$ belongs to $p\hat E(p\mathbb{Z}_p) = \hat E(p^2\mathbb{Z}_p)$ by looking at the valuation at a parameter $t(Q)=-x(Q)/y(Q)$ of the formal group.

Refined versions of this will work for any type of reduction over any local field.

Comment: The Sage code given in the previous post (now deleted) was not working. Can you suggest some other code for computing the $p$-torsion over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ ?

Comment: Yes, it was working. And for small $p$ it is very good to use that code. Otherwise the above translates easily to code. But this site is not meant to answer that sort of questions.

Comment: I tried for $p=11$. May be that's why it was not working.

Comment: sage: E = EllipticCurve("57a1")
sage: Ep = E.base_extend(Qp(11,100))
sage: f = Ep.torsion_polynomial(11)
sage: r = f.roots()
sage: len(r)
0
shows that there are no11-torsion on that curve over $\mathbb{Q}_{11}$.